# Computation complexity of an exponential function

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

How we compute the computation complexity of an exponential function like $a^x$ where $a,x \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|a|=l$ bits and $|x|=m$ bits?
Can anyone please explain using big notation?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions.

Comment: @nbro, I've corrected my mistake for typing $b$ instead of $x$. can you please suggest a good article or book section for Big-O notation and computational complexity measure?

Answer (score 1):

The result has roughly $l\cdot x=l\cdot 2^m$ bits. Hence $\Omega(l\cdot 2^m)$ is a lower bound both for the time complexity and thus for the running time of every specific algorithm.

On the other hand, let's look at one specific algorithm. The exponentiation can be done with $\Theta(m)$ multiplications, the $i$-th of which dealing with numbers of $\Theta(l\cdot 2^i)$ bits. Multiplication of $n$ bit numbers can be done in $\Theta(n\cdot\log n)$ time. This gives a total of

$\Theta\left(\sum_{1\leq i\leq m}l\cdot 2^i\cdot\log(l\cdot 2^i)\right)$

$=\Theta\left(l\cdot\log l\cdot\sum_{1\leq i\leq m}2^i + l\cdot\sum_{1\leq i\leq m}2^i\cdot i\right)$

$=\Theta\left(l\cdot\log l\cdot 2^m+l\cdot m\cdot 2^m\right)$

$=\Theta(l\cdot(\log l+m)\cdot2^m)$

Here we have a matching upper and lower bound for the running time of the algorithm. On the other hand, it is just one algorithm, so for the time complexity all it gives us is an upper bound $O(l\cdot(\log l+m)\cdot 2^m)$. 
Observe that it does not match the lower bound from above.

Comment: The question specifically asks for big notation, but yours seems to be the ordinary size!

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I read "big notation" as a shorthand for "big $O$/$\Omega$/$\Theta$-notation". I am not aware of any other meaning of the term. Please enlighten me.